# CSS not working on firefox but working in chrome

Tags: css, wordpress

I've used this css custom style on wordpress to style a translation widget.

```
.transposh-bar{
display:block;
background-color:#fff;
padding: 3px 10px;
}
.transposh-widget{
        display:block;
    padding-left:88%;
}
```

and this for mobile:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {.transposh-widget{
    display:block;
    padding-left:3%;
}
}
```

This is the code to style:

```
 <div class="transposh-bar">
         <div class="transposh-widget">
      <?php if(function_exists("transposh_widget")) { transposh_widget(array(), array('title' => 'Translation', 'widget_file' => 'select2/tpw_select2.php'),true); }?>
    </div>
```

On Chrome all is styled fine, instead on firefox it isn't styled. 
What's wrong?

Comment: clear the cache of firefox ?

Comment: Yes, I've tryed now.. It was that.. Sorry.. :)

Comment: Since it is unlikely to ever help anyone else, rather than providing an answer you should have deleted it. That's what is going to eventually happen to it anyway (by community vote).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was only the Firefox Cache